# Problem after updating opencv

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, pi-2, raspbian-jessie

I am using raspberry pi 3 jessian 
I tried to update my opencv using 
Sudo pip install opencv-contrib -python

Now i cant import cv2 in any program .

Thanks in advance for any help. I am really in trouble

Comment: Really?? Nobody has any ideas??

Comment: Yelling at people who might want to help you actually makes them not want to help you.

Comment: I didn't mean that actually. Even though if it was reflected that way, i do apologize about it. Sorry if i have insulted anyone. Really sorry...

Comment: OK. OpenCV is really horribly complicated and upgrading is dangerous because they keep changing their minds about the API so all the programs keep breaking. It's very annoying.  I often want to scream when dealing with OpenCV. What works is installing a version and sticking with it for years if need be. Recommend you uninstall and reinstall. OpenCV is a pain.

Comment: Dear OyaMist , thank you so much about your response , appreciate it.

Comment: Don't you need to update `opencv` also, with `sudo pip install opencv-python`? I think `opencv` and `opencv-contrib` both need to be the same versions(if you have them both installed). That's my geuss, though I'm not an opencv expert...

Comment: @scitronboy thanks for your feedback but I destroyed everything  right now, installing everything again): i would have tried your comment if possible